# Heroku changes in html not detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pushing my app to heroku like usual:

```
git add .
git commit -m  "blabla"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

I made changes in html for example in title or even in body - like changed text on the page
But I can't see this changes on `mysite.herokuapp.com` - what can be the problem?

Comment: I also disabled cache in my browser

Comment: Im assuming you have actually checked you have made changes to those files. Also that isn't server side caching thats the problem. As a next step you can open a console on the heroku server. `heroku open console`(the command may have changed and you will need the heroku toolbelt) But that will give you a console directly on the server. Check the files you are changing.

Comment: many **many** reasons, are you pushing to the correct remote? Is the push actually going through? Have you tried force pushing it? Have you tried checking the logs on Heroku? We need more `information`